# Checkbox default value don't update table

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I have a checkbox code :

```
<div data-ng-repeat="data in displayCollection | unique:'statut_ticket_id_statut'"> 
                <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="data.libelle" ng-checked="data.libelle === 'Opened'" />  {{data.libelle}}  </div>
```

It display some checkboxes and if i check them it update the table below with the checkbox filters.

I've set the checkbox "Opened" checked by default.

It works, the checkbox is checked but the table below is not updated.

I have to uncheck that default checkbox and check it again to make it works.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Use *ng-true-value* to tell AngularJS which value should be assigned to *data.libelle* when the box is checked.

```
<input type="checkbox"  ng-model="data.libelle" ng-true-value="'Opened'" ng-false-value="'closed'" />
```

https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/docs/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

Comment: what if I have multiple checkboxes with different status like : "Opened", "Closed", "Waiting" etc... I have like 7 status different which means 7 checkboxes to display, and I display all of them thank to the "ng-repeat".